# Current user receive Broadcast Event even with toOthers() method with Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, broadcast

Have you ever used broadcasting with the toOthers() method?

My app uses that and the Event is broadcasted fine.

Problem: it broadcasts the event also to the current user.

The event emits on a PresenceChannel named onlineUsers and the InteractsWithSockets Trait is used in the event class as well.
I added $this->dontBroadcastToCurrentUser(); just in case in the class constructor but now I am running out of idea.

I use Laravel 6.8.

Here is my Listener from which the broadcast is called:

```
namespace App\Listeners\Auth;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;

use App\User;


class LogSuccessfulLogin implements ShouldQueue
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  object  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(Login $event)
    {
        $logged_user = User::find($event->user->id);

        // Notify connected users within website
        $message = $logged_user->first_name." just logged in";
        broadcast(new \App\Events\NewLoginUserMessage($message))->toOthers();

    }
}
```

Here is the Event class:

```
namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NewLoginUserMessage implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->dontBroadcastToCurrentUser();
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PresenceChannel('onlineUsers');
    }

    /**
     * Get the data to broadcast.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return ['message' => $this->message];
    }
}
```

All the users in the presence Channel "onlineUsers" are receiving the notification.

Why is the current user also receiving the notification from the event?

What did I missed?

Answer (score 3):

Found this question today since I ran into such problem myself. Maybe this information will be useful to someone. I had the the same issue when posting data from stand-alone SPA by axios. Both dontBroadcastToCurrentUser() and toOthers() methods work based on the socket ID which must be passed to the request as X-Socket-ID. The X-Socket-ID header is attached to response automatically when you use Vue scaffolding. In my case I had to add socked ID manually using axios interceptors. So I would advise you to check for the presence of this header in the request.

Check the "Configuration" chapter  https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/broadcasting#only-to-others